# Some tweet links does not work when using WKWebView to display a embedded twitter timeline

Tags: swift, twitter, wkwebview

I'm trying to use `WKWebView` to display one embedded timeline from Twitter.

Almost all links are working after the `WKWebView` has loaded the embedded content successfully, but the redirect link for each tweet which displays on the timeline does not.

Here is the embedded tweet link:

https://publish.twitter.com/?query=%40Google&widget=Timeline

This is the embedded twitter timeline:

```html
< a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/Google?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">Tweets by Google< /a> 
< script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8">< /script>
```

If you scroll it down and try to click one of the tweets, you will be lead to the current tweet, but this will not work when you display with `WKWebView`.

---

During my test round, I tried to use the same embedded timeline and tested on an Android device which worked.

I think the embedded link is fine and it must be something wrong with how I implemented `WKWebView` or the `WKWebView` itself has issues with displaying a Twitter Embedded Timeline.

---

Here is my code for using `WKWebView` to display the embedded Twitter timeline:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private var mWebView: WKWebView!
    let embeddedTwittContent = "<a class='twitter-timeline' href='https://twitter.com/Google?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw'>Tweets by Google</a>"
    let scriptValue = "<script async src=\"https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js\" charset=\"utf-8\"></script>"
    let redirectLink = "https://twitter.com/Smaforetagarna/status/"


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        let preferences = WKPreferences()
        preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true

        let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        configuration.websiteDataStore =  WKWebsiteDataStore.nonPersistent()
        configuration.preferences = preferences

        self.mWebView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect.zero, configuration: configuration)

        self.mWebView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.mWebView.allowsLinkPreview = true
        self.mWebView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
        self.mWebView.navigationDelegate = self
        self.view.addSubview(self.mWebView)

        // Add Constraints
        self.mWebView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true
        self.mWebView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        self.mWebView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        self.mWebView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

        loadTweetNews()
    }

    func loadTweetNews(){
        let htmlHeader = "<!DOCTYPE html> <html><meta name=\'viewport\' content=\'initial-scale=1.0\'/> <head> \(scriptValue) </head> <body>"
        let htmlFooter = "</body> </html>"
        let orderHtml = htmlHeader + embeddedTwittContent + htmlFooter
        let url: URL = URL(string: "https:")!

        self.mWebView.loadHTMLString(orderHtml, baseURL: url)
    }


}

extension ViewController: WKNavigationDelegate{
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        print("page finished load")
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didReceiveServerRedirectForProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        print("didReceiveServerRedirectForProvisionalNavigation: \(navigation.debugDescription)")
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        print("didStartProvisionalNavigation")
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        if navigationAction.navigationType == .linkActivated  {
            if let url = navigationAction.request.url,
                UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(url)
                print(url)
                decisionHandler(.cancel)
            } else {
                decisionHandler(.allow)
            }
        } else {
            decisionHandler(.allow)
        }
    }

}
```

If you run this code, you will be able to click almost all links, but as soon you trying to click one of these tweets, nothing will happen.

---

My project deployment target is `10.0`

My Xcode version is `10.2.1`

My Swift version is `4.2`

Comment: This was also reported on the Twitter [dev forums](https://twittercommunity.com/t/embedded-tweet-doesnt-load-completely-sometimes-in-wkwebview/126169/) and I think it is being looked into.

Comment: I do not think this is related to the same issue Andy Piper. In my case, almost everything is working but expect the tweet redirect link which shall be like "https://twitter.com/Google/status/<id>".